# Useing CIFilter to create image cause rendering very slow on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I use CIFilter to create a UIImage then add it on a UIImageView. The process of creating this image is really fast and I can add it on the image view. But the whole UI is freeze for a few seconds until it shows the filtered image. I checked that the CIFilter call is fast. I think the slow is caused by UIImageView to render the image. Why is it such slow if the image already created? Below is the code to make a filter of a image.

```
func photoEffectChrome() -> CIFilter {
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectChrome")!
    return (filter)
}

func outputImage(filter: CIFilter, originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage{
    print(filter)
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: originalImage)
    filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let cgImage = context!.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, fromRect: (filter.outputImage?.extent)!)
    return UIImage(CGImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)
}
```

The call on the above methods happens on a background thread, then I use blow method to add it on a scroll view.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.filterScrollView.addSubview(uiView)
        })
```

If I comment out the "self.filterScrollView.addSubview(uiView)", the UI runs smoothly. Why does it take a long time for rendering the image? More specifically, it happens on simulator. It works much faster when running on a device.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

> But the whole UI is freeze for a few seconds until it shows the filtered image

A problem of this sort suggests that the method in which you set the UIImageView's `image` (not shown in your question) is being called on a background thread. You mustn't do that.

Comment: I have put these two methods call on a background thread. And only call addSubViews() on main thread. But it still block the UI. It seems that the method call on addSubView() block the UI. I don't understand that if the image already generated why rendering it on UI takes such a long time.

Comment: If you are only calling `addSubview` on the main thread, then you are doing other things to the image view on a background thread. I am saying _not_ to do that. You continue to conceal all the code that is actually important to this question, so I can't give you more specific help...

Comment: @matt I am actually not sure that is the problem here. I am having the same problem, executing the filter on `DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInteractive` and posting via `NotificationCenter` on `DispatchQueue.main.async` to update the image view. I see the same UI lag. The filter application takes only `t<0.03s` measured with `ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime` difference. But loading the image into the image view seems to cause the lag.

Comment: @matt The lag only occurs in the simulator, not on a real device (tested on iPhone Xs Max). My guess is that on the simulator CoreImage is not using the GPU, hence it is slow. There are in fact many SO questions regarding this, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53461592/1870795

Comment: Regarding general performance optimizations rendering a `CIImage` see this brilliant article: https://academy.realm.io/posts/tryswift-gladman-simon-advanced-core-image/

Comment: @Manuel If that's really the issue, try updating to Xcode 11. The simulator _does_ use the GPU there. (I agree that my answer is probably wrong, but if I delete it we lose these comments, so I'll wait a while before I do that!)