# Core Image GPU performance too slow

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I was playing with Core Image Filters and encountered a strange benchmark.
With the following 2 functions; one processing heavy math on cpu and other on gpu as the name suggests, cpu performance is about a hundred times faster than the gpu performance. I tried "CILineOverlay" and "CIPhotoEffectProcess" filters and measured the transforming time with `DispatchTime.now()` method.
Am I doing something wrong? Or is it related to deprecated opengl support?

```
private func apply_cpu(to image:UIImage?, appleFilterName:String) -> UIImage?    {

    guard let image = image, let cgimg = image.cgImage else {
        return nil
    }

    let coreImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgimg)

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
    filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter?.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

    if let output = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
        return UIImage(ciImage: output)
    }

    else {
        return nil
    }
}


private func apply_gpu(to image:UIImage?, appleFilterName:String)-> UIImage?  {

    guard let image = image, let cgimg = image.cgImage else {

        return nil
    }


    let coreImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgimg)


    let start = DispatchTime.now()

    let openGLContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES3)
    let context = CIContext(eaglContext: openGLContext!) 


    guard let filter = CIFilter(name: appleFilterName)   else {
        return nil
    }

    if  filter.inputKeys.contains(kCIInputImageKey) {
        filter.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    }

    if  filter.inputKeys.contains(kCIInputIntensityKey) {


    }


    if let output = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
        let cgimgresult = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgimgresult!)

    }

        return nil

}
```

}

Comment: Ok. First thought, without checking your code. Are you using the simulator or an actual device? The simulator *doesn't* use the GPU, which CoreImage is most definitely gear towards. (For me the simulator takes "seconds to minutes", and a device takes "near real time to milliseconds".) I'll look at your code but that's the first thing I needed to ask.

Comment: Ok! A quick glance at your code has me wondering more. First, What kind of testing are you doing? What calls `apply_cpu` and `apply_gpu`? That may make **much** difference. Here's three things I do (keep in mind this is without knowing *how* you are using these two functions), listed in order of what may be wrong. (1) Depending on how you are calling `apply_gpu` you may be creating a `CIContext` every single time where you can (and absolutely should) only be using a single shared one. This is very expensive!

Comment: (2) I see you passing in a `UIImage` to both functions. Why? Since any CoreImage filter *requires* a `CIImage`, just change it as soon as possible - and only change it back to a UIImage as needed. (Remember, a CIImage is **not* a real image, but rather a "recipe" of the image.) Finally, (3) ... nope. Sorry, I was writing too quick. :-) Using `UIImage(ciImage:)` sometimes doesn't give you what you want when trying to make a UIImage from a CIImage. But I've never come across something where an actual UIImage doesn't create a CIImage properly the way you are. I hope something I mentioned helped.

Comment: @ dfd . you are right, I am running on the simulator. I run it on my iphone and it is super fast. Thank you vey much. I had also removed EAGLContext initialization code to constructor since I read it somewhere, too, that it is expensive. But it hadn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad  my first instinct did it. I've never found any resource that addresses this, much less mentions it. I learned the hard way (except I had a test device where I tried real quickly afterwards). If there's a second thing to remember, it's to try to use a single `CIContext` where you can. (Bonus, use a `GLKView` - dedicated but still works for now - or a `MLKView` instead of a `UIImageView`. Only make it a `UIImage` if necessary.) EDIT: I don't know if it's the `EAGLContext` that is costly, bt I've always heard it's the `CIContext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, the issue was where the performance time tests were being done. I can't stress this enough when testing `CoreImage` filters:

**Use a *real* device, not the simulator.**

My experience is that it can take "seconds to minutes" in the simulator where in any iPhone 5 or later device using iOS 9+ (maybe earlier too, both ways) will be "near real-time to milliseconds". If you aren't seeing this on a real device? There *is* something wrong in the code.

I've not found any tutorials, any books, anything at all that stresses this single point. My best resource - Simon Gladman who wrote the excellent *Core Image for Swift* (be careful, it's Swift 2) - explains a lot of what I believe is going on, but never really stressed why it is the case.

An iOS device uses the GPU. A simulator *does not*.

I'm sure it's more complex than that and involves optimization. But the thing is this - while you can use CoreImage in `macOS`, if you are using the simulator you are targeting `iOS`. So where a macOS project using CoreImage may perform well, if it's an iOS project you need to use a real device to get a real feel for performance.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm doing TONS of CoreImage stuff with WebRTC (ie, trying to get 30 fps or more) and it wasn't too far into it when I realized that using the simulator was very problematic but using a device (in my case, a 6th gen iPod Touch) was night/day difference.